# jquery plugin which puts a transparent overlay over a div with a loader in the center

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jquery plugin as described in the title and it has to be cross browser compatible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This you could *make*, have you tried anything (at all) or is this a shopping question?

Comment: Have you tried writing one yourself, its pretty simple to do - [look here for help authoring plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: I thought the point of a plugin was to save you having to code it yourself

Comment: They don't magaically appear out of thin air though, *somebody* has to write them. And as you have a very narrow, specific requirement you might like to write one yourself!

Comment: Might find what you're looking for here: http://designmodo.com/css3-jquery-loading-animations/

Comment: You can also use [center-loader](https://github.com/rohitkhatri/center-loader) plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at BlockUI

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/